# Symbolically Expanding One-Variable $q$-hypergeometric Series

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

In general, how do I get *Mathematica* to symbolically expand various infinite series to an arbitrary degree of accuracy?  I deal with $q$-hypergeometric series quite frequently, and specifically want to expand series like the following: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nq^{6n^2}}{(q^3;q^3)_n(-q;q)_{3n}},$$ where $(a;q)_n$ denotes the standard $q$-Pochhammer symbol $\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-aq^k)$.  I would like to input a maximal degree, and for *Mathematica* to output the first few terms of the infinite series up until the specified degree. For example, if I inputted $13$, I would want *Mathematica* to output (I believe, doing this by hand) $q^6-q^7+q^{10}-q^{11}+q^{12}-q^{13}$.  I cannot get the existing series functions to give something as clean as what I want.

One preliminary input I tried was

```
FunctionExpand[Sum[(-1)^n/QPochhammer[q^3, q^3, n], {n, 0, 10}]]
```

which returned

```
1 - 1/(1 - 
  q^3) + 1/((1 - q^3) (1 - q^6)) - 1/((1 - q^3) (1 - q^6) (1 - 
    q^9)) + 1/((1 - q^3) (1 - q^6) (1 - q^9) (1 - q^12)) - 1/((1 - 
    q^3) (1 - q^6) (1 - q^9) (1 - q^12) (1 - q^15)) + 1/((1 - 
    q^3) (1 - q^6) (1 - q^9) (1 - q^12) (1 - q^15) (1 - 
    q^18)) - 1/((1 - q^3) (1 - q^6) (1 - q^9) (1 - q^12) (1 - 
    q^15) (1 - q^18) (1 - q^21)) + 1/((1 - q^3) (1 - q^6) (1 - 
    q^9) (1 - q^12) (1 - q^15) (1 - q^18) (1 - q^21) (1 - 
    q^24)) - 1/((1 - q^3) (1 - q^6) (1 - q^9) (1 - q^12) (1 - 
    q^15) (1 - q^18) (1 - q^21) (1 - q^24) (1 - q^27)) + 1/((1 - 
    q^3) (1 - q^6) (1 - q^9) (1 - q^12) (1 - q^15) (1 - q^18) (1 - 
    q^21) (1 - q^24) (1 - q^27) (1 - q^30)),
```

which is not the form of output that I want because the sum is not fully expanded as a polynomial in $q$.  Also, if I insert an additional `QPochhammer[-q, q, Infinity]` out front, it leaves the $(-q;q)_{\infty}$ unexpanded because there is no degree specification.  (This is why I want to implement the degree specification rather than settling for expanded partial sums.)  These are two central issues that I'm not sure how to address.

Comment: Post examples of what you've tried and the results vs what you require. More likely to get help that way.

Answer (score 7):

Is this is what you are after?

```
Series[Sum[(-1)^n/QPochhammer[q^3, q^3, n], {n, 0, 10}], {q, 0, 10}] // Normal

(*  1 + q^6 + q^9   *)
```

Comment: I was about to say the same thing `Series[Sum[(-1)^n q^(6 n^2)/( QPochhammer[-q,q,3n]QPochhammer[q^3,q^3,n]),{n,0,20}],{q,0,13}]`

Answer (score 6):

Just for reference, the sum depicted in the OP has a representation in terms of the $q$-hypergeometric function. In particular,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nq^{6n^2}}{(q^3;q^3)_n(-q;q)_{3n}}={}_1\phi_4\left({{0}\atop{-q,-q^2,-q^3,0}}\mid q^3,-q^6\right)$$

Compare:

```
Series[QHypergeometricPFQ[{0}, {-q, -q^2, -q^3, 0}, q^3, -q^6], {q, 0, 15}]
   1 - q^6 + q^7 - q^10 + q^11 - q^12 + q^13 - q^14 + q^15 + O[q]^16

% - FunctionExpand[Sum[((-1)^n q^(6 n^2))/
                       (QPochhammer[q^3, q^3, n] QPochhammer[-q, q, 3 n]), {n, 0, 15}]]
   O[q]^16
```